# Can we hook function calls in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I am on a very old MFC application and a lot of callbacks for GUI defined as follows which are spread across 100's of cpp files across different views/documents

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OP1, OnFileOp1)

ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_FILE_OP1, OnUpdateFileOp1)

ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OP2, OnFileOp2)

ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_FILE_OP2, OnUpdateFileOp2)
```

A new requirement requires me to call a function after and before every `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI`'s defined call back function  call and `ON_COMMAND` as well.

I am trying to create a `#define` so that a change is localised and works as a hooking mechanism for the call back begin end maybe.

I can definitely call my common function after and before each function call but I don't think that as a clean approach.

Whats the standard or a good approach for this ?

I wish to hook to `ON_COMMAND` & `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` call back functions cleanly from outside.

I am on Windows, Visual Studio 2015 x64.

Answer (score -2):

You can install a hook procedure by calling the SetWindowsHookEx function ... To retrieve a handle to the DLL module, call the LoadLibrary function with the ... wParam, szMsg, c++); if (FAILED(hResult)) { // TODO: writer error ...

Comment: how can i hook to ON_COMMAND which is macro . Can you please give an example please

Comment: `SetWindowsHookEx` doesn't allow you to hook function calls. `LoadLibrary` doesn't return an `HRESULT`. If it fails, it returns `NULL`, which happens to be the same value assigned to `S_OK`. The proposed error checking isn't just useless, it's actively harmful.